# Can I put nosetests command-line options in a configuration file?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, nose

I'd like to put the command-line options I prefer for `nosetests` into a file, so they'll travel with my repo.  The docs are unclear, at best, or maybe just wrong, about how this can be done.

[nose's documentation](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) mentions a ".noserc or nose.cfg file" but when I added the following to either of them, nothing changes-

```
[nosetests]
nocapture=1
verbosity=3
```

These are the equivalent of `nosetests -vvv --nocapture`.

Comment: You should provide the actual command you're running. If you're not already providing it, the [`-c`/`--config` option](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#options) should let you explicitly pass the file's location into `nosetests`, so there shouldn't be any ambiguity about whether nose is reading your config.

Comment: @kungphu While that's true, ideally I'd like for users to just type `nosetests` and not be required to know anything else about it. `nosetests` has enough vagueness in its docs that I'd like to avoid requiring users or committers to learn any more about it.

Comment: Understandable, but shouldn't someone who wants or needs to run the tests be able to at least copy and paste the right flag from the readme? Particularly contributors, who should presumably be either writing tests for their changes or building patches to address existing test failures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setup.cfg` is a third filename that `nosetests` recognizes as a source for project-level command-line options.  [`nosetests` looks in the current folder for `setup.cfg`, and `.noserc` or `nose.cfg`](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) in your home directory.

The docs "`.noserc` or `nose.cfg`" in the first paragraph, but doesn't mention `setup.cfg` until deeper in the page.